# System function in Python that allows interactivity

Tags: python, function

I am trying to find the equivalent of the Perl system function (or backticks) and while there are plenty of answers out there, they do not seem to cover certain cases. Specifically, when the desired system call will require some input back from the user.

for example, when using ssh to perform a command on a server where key authentication is not set up:

`ssh -l user1 server1 \"ls -la`;
would prompt the user to provide a password:

user1@server1's password:

and if no command was provided, then an interactive session would be started, and presumably the user would want to be able to do things in the session.

This is 1 case, there are others (scp, triggering another script with user input, for example) where this occurs, and I am looking for something that would allow using any command that fits these criteria.

Comment: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: If you do things like this you should look into Fabric which is geared toward using Python for SSH connections but can also run commands locally. It provides the dialogues.

Comment: This is answered in many different questions, all leading to subprocess module.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD. Remove the incorrect tag.